# trying to append querystring with rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to do a very simple rewrite rule and having no luck.  What I want to do is take all traffic that comes to a specific page and append a static query string.
This is what I am doing and it does not append anything:

```
RewriteRule ^/subdir/test.html$ /subdir/test.html?utm_source=delta&utm_medium=radio&utm_campaign=test [QSA,L]
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Many thanks in advance!

I will answer my own question in case someone else has this problem.  You need to add an additional condition to make sure the query string is empty or it will keep appending inn a loop.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$

Comment: I have also tried this and get a redirect loop error:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir/test.html$
        RewriteRule (.*) /subdir/test.html?utm_source=delta&utm_medium=radio&utm_campaign=test [R=301,L,QSA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question in case someone else has this problem. You need to add an additional condition to make sure the query string is empty or it will keep appending in a loop.

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$